# Is this an idiom or not?

Tags: idioms

I heard one of Glen Hansard's song named 'grace beneath the pines' Is it an idiomarticle phrase ? I found another song with the same title, that's why I started to think about some special meaning of this phrase. I understand what Mr. Hansard sings about, and grace beneath the pines I can also understand literally. There's nothing seems unlogical. But I guess he means something I can't understand just because I'm not a native English speaking person. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is no rigid mechanism to determine what is or isn't an "idiom".  But "grace beneath the pines" is not familiar to me, and I suspect it is not well known and hence does not achieve the minimum familiarity needed to be considered an "idiom".  It may, of course, be a metaphor, but one can't determine that without knowing more about it's origins.

Answer (score 1):

"Grace beneath the pines" is not idiomatic; it's idiosyncratic to the songwriter Glenn Hansard, who wrote and performs a song of the same name.

In the song, Hansard finds grace in various situations:

> Now I found some
>  Grace beneath the judge's gavel,
>  Grace
>   among my brothers on the firing line,
>  Grace upon this road less
>   travelled,
>   **Grace beneath the pines**, the pines

The first locations seem fairly straightforward -- upon judgment, during strife, following one's singular destiny -- but the pines seems less so.

Here is Hansard's [explanation](http://music.cbc.ca/#!/blogs/2015/9/Glen-Hansards-Didnt-He-Ramble-a-track-by-track-guide) for the lyric:

> Songs ... just show up when they want, they don't keep any
>   appointments. They tend to come in the middle of chaos. I was at a
>   festival in Austria, and I was trying to avoid the main stage because
>   I wasn't enjoying the music at all. And I ran off into the forest and
>   was kind of writing the lyric for that song. So 'grace beneath the
>   pines' — that's where that line came from.